# Prometheus CPU Usage Histogram Metrics

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, quantile, cadvisor

my goal is to observe metrics (like CPU, Memory usage etc.) with Prometheus on a server and on its running docker containers. Before sending an alarm, I would like to compare the certain values of those metrics with e.g. an 0.95 quantile. However, over several weeks of search in the internet I still struggle to create metrics for the certain quantiles. Therefore I ask in this thread for your help/advice, how a quantile for certain metrics can be created.

## Background

The code base is a fork of the [docprom](https://github.com/stefanprodan/dockprom) repository. This code relies on Prometheus for monitoring. Prometheus retrieves its data from a running `cAdvisor` container. The provided metrics of cAdvisor for Prometheus can be seen on the following [page](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/master/docs/storage/prometheus.md). However, it provides only `Gauge` and `Counter` metric types. During my research I was not able to find parameters that would enable modifications/extensions of those provided metrics.

## Problem

According to my current understanding, the metric type should be a `Histogram` or `Summary` in order to observe the quantiles. What is the best approach to use the `histogram_quantile` query on the metrics provided by cAdvisor?

My current idea is to

1. create a custom server
2. fetch the desired data from Prometheus
3. calculate the desired data
4. provide it as a metric from the server, so that Prometheus can scrape it
5. Run `histogram_quantile` on the custom metric

Is it the right approach in order to create a metric that can be used with quantiles?

For example I would like to fire an alarm if a certain containers' CPU usage exceeds a 0,95 quantile. The code for the CPU usage can be seen exemplary below:

`sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{name="CONTAINER_NAME"}[10m])))  / count(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="system"}) * 100`

What would be the best approach to create the desired quantiles? Am I on the right path or am I missing something simple here? Because it looks way too hard for me in order to get a simple query with a quantile.

I am thankful for all help and information.

Comment: did you manage how to do it?